# Associate Work Items to a Pull Request Programmatically

Tags: git, azure-devops, pull-request

I can get (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/pull-requests#get-a-pull-request) a pull request, manage reviewers and complete it. The branch has a policy requiring work items and it fails as the pull request does not automatically add the work items associated with the underlying commits.

Poking at the PATCH against the pull request with bad parameters nets a

> "You can only update reviewers, descriptions, titles, merge status,
>   and status"

I can get a list of work items using the pull requests url + /workitems but POST, PUT and PATCH all are not supported on the collection.

I do not see a way to associate a work item with the pull request?

Comment: Do you success linking pull request to work item or vote that user voice?

Comment: I voted on the issue as there seems to be no programmatic way at this time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can associate work item to a pull request by updating the work item links just as starain mentioned.

Not sure which code language you use, I added a C# code sample for your reference:

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch.Json;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models;

namespace PRWIl
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string tfsurl = "https://xxx.visualstudio.com/";
            TfsTeamProjectCollection ttpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(tfsurl));
            GitHttpClient ghc = ttpc.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();
            string project = "ProjectName";
            string repoid = "repositoryid";
            int pullrequestid = 1;
            int workitemid = 1;
            GitPullRequest gpr = ghc.GetPullRequestAsync(project,repoid,pullrequestid).Result;

            WorkItemTrackingHttpClient withc = ttpc.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();

            JsonPatchDocument json = new JsonPatchDocument();

            string pullrequesturl = "vstfs:///Git/PullRequestId/" + gpr.Repository.ProjectReference.Id + "%2F" + gpr.Repository.Id + "%2F" + gpr.PullRequestId;
            json.Add(new JsonPatchOperation
            {
                Operation = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch.Operation.Add,
                Path = "/relations/-",
                Value = new WorkItemRelation() {Rel = "ArtifactLink", Url = pullrequesturl }
            });
            WorkItem result = withc.UpdateWorkItemAsync(json,workitemid).Result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported to associate work items to a pull request through REST API or client SDK API.

You can vote this user voice (https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/15954904-rest-api-create-or-update-pull-request-with-work-i)

The workaround is that you could link pull request to work item. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#add-a-link (The pull request URL could be found in the response after you link another work item, so you could link a work item to pull request manually, then link another work item to that work item through REST API and check the response)

Comment: I need this to be done programmatically so "manually linking" to get the URL is not going to work.

A sample link to a pull request form a work item looks like ""vstfs:///Git/PullRequestId/44538c6a-0dbe-4251-bc4b-ca0859243d8e%2f2d89570f-a036-4ccd-a392-f81864f788b4%2f794""

Getting a pull request from the REST API does not populate the self link so I'm scratching my head as to what IDs to use to generate the right link to associate.

Is the pull request URL comprised of the GUIDs representing the from and to of the pull request when it was created?

Comment: @MontaneHamilton The format of pull request URL is vstfs://vstfs:///Git/PullRequestId/[project id]%2F[respository id]%2F[pull request id]. All these values are included in the response of specific pull request (https://[XX].visualstudio.com/[team project]/_apis/git/repositories/[respository name[/pullRequests/[pull request id]?api-version=1.0-preview.1

Comment: @MontaneHamilton Sample JSON to link pull request to work item. [
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value": {
      "rel": "ArtifactLink",
      "url": "vstfs:///Git/PullRequestId/b8ee4b6d-d5a8-4e3d-a7f8-f2da9713a830%2Fa4adf519-e040-4ea7-895e-8473d319f229%2F6",
      "attributes": {
        "comment": "Making a new link test"
      }
    }
  }

]

Comment: Yes I totally see how to make the link, I'm not sure how to get the pull request link itself. It does not seem available when I get the pull request via the API.

Comment: @MontaneHamilton You need to combine them (team project ID, repository id ...) together to generate a new URL according to the format that I said.

Comment: @MontaneHamilton Do you success linking pull request to work item now?

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable now.  Here is sample code snippet:

```
List<GitPullRequest> pullRequests = gitClient.GetPullRequestsAsync(
    repoId, GetPullRequestSearchCriteria(devBranch)).Result.Where
    p => p.ClosedDate > masterPullRequest.ClosedDate).ToList();

List<ResourceRef> resourceRef = new List<ResourceRef>();

foreach (GitPullRequest pullRequest in pullRequests)
{
    resourceRef.AddRange(gitClient.GetPullRequestAsync(
        repoId, pullRequest.PullRequestId, includeWorkItemRefs: true).Result.WorkItemRefs);
}

GitPullRequest gitPullRequest = new GitPullRequest()
{
    Title = "Sprint 9",
    TargetRefName = masterBranch,
    SourceRefName = devBranch,
    WorkItemRefs = resourceRef.ToArray()
};

GitPullRequest g = gitClient.CreatePullRequestAsync(gitPullRequest, repoId).Result;
```

Comment: Plenty details are outlined here: https://markheath.net/post/automate-prs-azure-devops