# VSTS - Add Work Item with PullRequest

Tags: c#, azure-devops, libgit2sharp

We have an automated tool in c# and using "libgit2sharp" API, it will do Clone Repository, Stage file, Commit and Push the changes, Pull Request creation is done by REST API.

Now have to add a Work Item with the Pull Request, need suggestions to proceed.

Thanks,

Comment: Add `#1234` in the commit message.

Comment: What's the result after you trying to associate pull request to work item (refer to my solution)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static bool AddWorkItem()
    {
        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        string workItem = "12345678";
        string pullReqId = string.Empty;
        string artifactId = string.Empty;
        string moduleName = "abcd";


        pullReqId = "123456";
        artifactId = "vstfs:///Git/PullRequestId/xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx";
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://tfs-glo-xxxxxxxxx.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/workItems/" + workItem);

            request.Accept = "application/json;api-version=3.0;excludeUrls=true";
            request.ContentType = "application/json-patch+json";
            request.Referer = "https://tfs-glo-xxxxxxxxx.visualstudio.com/Apps/_git/" + moduleName + "/pullrequest/" + pullReqId + "?_a=overview";

            string _auth = string.Format("{0}:{1}", "GITUserName", "GITPassword");
            string _enc = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_auth));
            string _cred = string.Format("{0} {1}", "Basic", _enc);
            request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = _cred;

            request.Method = "PATCH";

            string body = @"[{""op"":0,""path"":""/relations/-"",""value"":{""attributes"":{""name"":""Pull Request""},""rel"":""ArtifactLink"",""url"":" + "\"" + artifactId + "\"" + "}}]";
            byte[] postBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
            request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
            Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
            stream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
            stream.Close();

            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Write("Add Work Item: ", ex);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported to associate work items to a pull request through REST API or client SDK API, but you could link pull request to work item through REST API. So the workflow will be like this:

1. Create pull request through REST API
2. Link that pull request to work item through REST API.

More information, you can check this thread for detail: [Associate Work Items to a Pull Request Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39352757/associate-work-items-to-a-pull-request-programmatically) (Include C# code)